# Using a wireless printer with an iPad

Tags: ipad

Why my iPad cannot find the wireless printe?
When I am using my laptop it is working fine because I installed the printer cd.How can I print when using my new iPad?

Comment: Which printer are you using? Are you sure it supports AirPrint? Have you tried the [AirPrint Setup and Troubleshooting](http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/assistant/airprint/) at Apple.com?

Comment: Its an HP wireless printer

Comment: Today's HP printers say that they support AirPrint.  Older ones, even wireless ones, don't.

Answer (score 2):

If your printer doesnt specifically support AirPlay try an app called Printopia.

http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/